# Python's str.replace not throwing an Exception

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Using `str.replace('a','b','l')` instead of `'aaa'.replace('a','b')`from the function `(S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str)`  returns 'a'.

I imagine the 'l' instead of an integer does not get read, since there's no match, but why does it return 'a' and not throw an exception?

Answer (score 3):

Because `str.replace('a','b','l')` is interpreted as `'a'.replace('b','l')`.

You're invoking the `method` of class `str` and explicitly passing the instance `'a'` here:

```
str.replace('a', ...) -> 'a'.replace(...)
```

instead of going the traditional way of implicitly passing the instance via `'a'.replace(...)`. So `'b'` and `'l'` are actually interpreted as the `old` and `new` arguments to `str.replace`.

If you supply a non-int as the value of `count` to `str.replace` you'll get your exception:

```
str.replace('a', 'a', 'b', '1')

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-f8b6e2752fe6> in <module>()
----> 1 str.replace('a', 'a', 'b', '2')

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: If 'a',.replace(...) then worse than str.replace(...) following the maxim: 'Explicit is better than implicit'.